# Relationship between photon polarization and photon angular momentum

Tags: visible-light, polarization, quantum-optics

What direction is the angular momentum of right hand polarized light points to? Is it vertical to its propagating direction? I want to recognize this in quantum theory.

Comment: have a look at http://teachers.web.cern.ch/teachers/archiv/HST2008/teacherslab/The%20photon%20angular%20momentum%20J%20KOSEK.ppt

Answer (score 2):

The spin of a right handed photon points in the direction of its momentum, while in a left handed photon it points in opposite way.

Comment: This is the answer to a slightly different question than the one asked here.

Answer (score 2):

A “right-handed” photon has its spin parallel to its linear momentum; a “left-handed” photon’s spin is antiparallel to its linear momentum. The psuedoscalar product $\vec\sigma\cdot\vec p$ is sometimes called the “helicity.”

Beware that “right-circular polarized” light is made of left-handed photons, and vice-versa (because history is cruel).
This is demonstrated conclusively in my favorite classic physics paper: Richard Beth, [Mechanical detection and measurement of the angular momentum of Light](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.50.115), Physical Review **50** 115 (1936). See [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/599694/44126) for a brief summary of Beth’s experiment.

Comment: Is it not true that there are two conventions for defining what left- and right-polarized light is?  It would seem that in one of the two conventions, RCP light comprises right-handed photons...

Comment: According to [an encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_polarization), the "helicity" convention is used by quantum physicists like me, radio astronomers, and the engineering society IEEE. Meanwhile the reversed "receiver-perspective" convention is used in optics textbooks (where I learned it), by the optics society SPIE, and by the chemists' society IUPAC. In conclusion, [ugh](https://xkcd.com/927/).