# Circular Polarization

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, polarization

Why we take left circularly polarized and right circularly polarized into account? Is there any physical difference between left circularly and right circularly polarized wave?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/599694/44126

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a very intuitive physical difference between left circularly polarized light and right circularly polarized light:

- left circularly polarized light gets transmitted through a left circular polarisation filter, while right circularly polarized light does not
- right circularly polarized light gets transmitted through a right circular polarisation filter, while left circularly polarized light does not

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you put your thumb in the direction of propagation of light, then as time passes, the electric field vector can move clockwise or anticlockwise only with the help of either your left hand or your right hand. Whichever hand it is gives the sense of polarisation.

This tells you the direction in which field vector moves as time passes.