# How do we measure angular momentum in Quantum Mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, experimental-physics, measurements

In QM, we define angular momentum as
$$\hat{\vec{L}}=\hat{\vec{r}}\times\hat{\vec{p}}$$
where $\hat{\vec{r}}$ and $\hat{\vec{p}}$ are the position and momentum operators.

My doubt is: we cannot measure both the position and the momentum of a particle at the same time, because they don't commute, so how do we measure the total angular momentum $\hat{L^2}$ or a component of angular momentum **in practice (in an experiment)?**

For example, if I want to measure $\hat{L_z}=\hat{x}\hat{p_y}-\hat{y}\hat{p_x}$ how can I do it without measuring both $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p_x}$ (and the same for $y$) at the same time?

---

EDIT: I realized that I am confused on how we measure also many other quantities. For example: how do we measure momentum? For a classical particle I would measure the positions at two different times and then divide the difference by the time interval (chosen as small as possible), but in QM when I first measure the position of a particle the state collapses, so the second measure would be on a different state. Moreover, the final state would not correspond to a collapse with respect to momentum, but a collapse with respect to position.

Comment: Another chance for me to mention [my favorite underrated classic physics paper](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/599694/44126), in which R. Beth used circularly polarized light to drive a torsion pendulum.

Comment: Someone else is better placed to give an experimental answer, but a note on a misconception you have - it is not that you cannot measure the position and momentum simultaneously AT ALL, but rather that the more precisely you know the one, the less precisely you know the other.

Comment: @MartinC. the Indetermination Principle applies to the variances of the position and momentum (or any couple of observables) probability distributions in a given quantum state. But what happens when I want to make only one experiment, not many? How does the wave function collapse if I want to measure two observables at the same time?

Comment: @rob how does this help me exactly? I'm confused

Comment: Your edit ([but see here for style guidance](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5886/44126)) may make this question “too broad.” The experiment described in the linked answer turns a quantum-mechanical spin into a macroscopic rotation.  Note that angular momentum is *one* observable, which is *related* to the noncommuting observables of position and momentum.