# Does a photon carry "end-over-end" angular momentum to explain skyrmions and other structured light?

Tags: photons, angular-momentum

It is widely known that photons carry a longitudinal angular momentum of ℏ, which is readily compared with circular polarization; the angular momentum vector for [right handed polarization](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64797/relationship-between-photon-polarization-and-photon-angular-momentum) has been arbitrarily designed to be in the direction of the photon's momentum.  However, the photon carries another perpendicular (?) orbital angular momentum of ℏ, for a total of sqrt(2) ℏ total.

I am wondering if the orbital angular momentum can be thought of simply as a perpendicular component of a spin or orbital angular momentum, i.e. a point particle with a diagonal angular momentum vector turning end over end as well as spinning, like the orbital angular momentum of an electron in a p orbital.  I have seen some argue that's impossible because it implies travelling faster than light, but I suspect there should be a limit you can write that provides a finite angular momentum from infinitesimal change in velocity.  Besides, [this landmark paper about skyrmions](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-021-26037-w.pdf) seems to *show exactly that* in its illustration of the "vortex rings", but they address light as a continuous wave rather than particles.  Orbital angular momentum is [none too easy to visualize as ordinarily presented](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-021-26253-4), so a simpler interpretation ... if true ... would really help to cut that Gordian knot down to size.  (The answer to this question is *probably* in that paper, but seeing it is another matter!)

Comment: (1) Circular-polarized photons carry longitudinal angular momentum, not transverse. (2) The electromagnetic field may, but need not, carry orbital angular momentum. The total squared spin is $S^2=S(S+1)\hbar=2\hbar$ like any other spin-one system. (3) The conventions for right-handed helicity and for left-circular polarization refer to the same state, because history is cruel.

Comment: @rob I fixed the first one - thinking like a biologist, I went for the transverse *plane*.  Ooops.  The third one I actually quoted from another Stackexchange question, which I've now credited, to see if I had it right...  I'll have to look that over again.  The second, well, I think you're saying with that the angular momentum vector for the photon *is* diagonal, not straight forward or backward, and so there *could* be a measurement of the ... transverse? ... end-over-end angular momentum

Comment: You would enjoy the classic paper by Beth (1936); see e.g. [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/599694/44126).